# Сообщение привысило максимально допустимый размер

Tags: c#, rest, office, outlook, office365

Я использую `Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.OutlookServicesClient` из библиотеки `Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices` для работы с Office 365 Outlook AAD.

Когда я пытаюсь получить одно из сообщений через его message-ID происходит следующая ошибка:

> "{
>   "error":
>   {"code":"ErrorMessageSizeExceeded","message":"The message exceeds the maximum supported size., The message exceeds the
>    maximum supported size."
>   }
>   }".

Есть ли способы решения этой проблемы? Я пробовал поменять максимально допустимые размеры сообщений через админку Office 365, это не помогло. Точнее это никаким образом не отразилось на получении отправки сообщений ни через API, ни через клиента.

Вот код получения сообщения на C#:

```
var messageQuery = m_user.Messages[messageSummary.MessageId];
IMessage message = await messageQuery.ExecuteAsync();
```